# The correct way of saying that the "decision has been made in my side"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

What is the correct way of saying the following?

> The decision has been made in my side.

We request the people that the decision be made on our side.

Answer (score 1):

["in one's favor"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20someone's%20favor)

"In one's favor" is the existing idiom to communicate what it is you're trying to say.  That would make your sentence:

> "The decision has been made in my favor."

-or-

> "We request that the decision be made in our favor."

Comment: I don't think it's got that far. The OP is asking how to write the given sentence idiomatically.

Comment: @marcellothearcane If the OP wants a correct or idiomatic version of the given sentence that does not change the word *side*, then the OP should brace for disappointment.

Answer (score -1):

For "the decision has been made in my side" I would simply say: "I decided" or "we decided" - if it is not only you but a group of people.
For the second quote: "We request the people that the decision be made on our side." I would say something like: "We request the people to let us decide." or "We request the people to let us make the decision."